# how to change checkbox size in datagridview winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

How I can change the size of the **checkbox** in the DataGridViewCheckBoxCell [NOT the size of the cell]
I am using .net 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to change the size of the square that's drawn insice the cell for a checkbox.
If thats the case I suspect there might not be a very easy solution to it, but you can acheive the results by custom painting images instead of the "Checked", "Unchecked" boxes. Here's a hint how to work that out..
Add two images (of the size you want since its the size that's important to you) in an imagelist on the form which contains your datagridview. (The two images will of course correspond to the Checked/Unchecked checkbox visual)
Handle "CellPainting" event of the DataGridView and write something like this:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)//Assuming the checkbox is in Column 0
        {
            e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
            int index = 0;//Unchecked image
            if (e.Value != null && (bool)e.Value == true)
                index = 1;//Checked image
                e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(imageList1.Images[index], e.CellBounds.X + 5, e.CellBounds.Y + 5);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Now in order to get checked/unchecked image in the cell all you need to do is set the value of the underlying datasource on the CellClick event (this is if you want that when user clicks on the cell the checkbox gets checked, if its read only then this might not be required)

NOTE: I am not sure if we can get a more elegant solution than this, please wait to see if someone has a brighter idea.