# How to change checkBox Size in DatagridviewCheckboxCell

Tags: c#, .net

I know the checkbox size can change like this.

```
checkBox1.Size = new Size(10, 10);
```

I want to change the checkbox size in DataGridview with DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn and I tried to inherit DatagridviewCheckboxCell,but ever found any way to do as same.

```
class DGCBC : DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
{
    public DGCBC()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DatagridviewCheckboxCustomCell();
    }

    class DatagridviewCheckboxCustomCell : DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
    {
        public int row_index { get; set; }
        /// <summary>   
        /// constructor   
        /// </summary>   
        /// 
        public DatagridviewCheckboxCustomCell()
        {
        }

        protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState,
         object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
         DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            *//I tried many way in there,but it's not work*
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you may post the code you tried.

Comment: Sorry,because I think override Paint seems the wrong direction,so hadn't  post.

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117477/how-to-change-checkbox-size-in-datagridview-winform

Answer (score 9):

To draw system controls in the current style of your machine you should use one of the many handy methods of the [ControlPaint class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is an example to draw three `Checkboxes` onto a `Panel`:

[image]

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, 11, 11, 22, 22, ButtonState.Checked);
    ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, 11, 44, 33, 33, ButtonState.Checked);
    ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, 11, 88, 44, 44, ButtonState.Checked);
}
```

Of course you need to adapt this in your `CellPainting` event to use the size you want and the coordinates of your cell!

Here is a simple example that pretty much **fills** the cell with the `CheckBox`:

[image]

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + 1, 
            e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 2,
            (bool) e.FormattedValue ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

You will want to find a size that suits your needs..

Note that you can combine some [ButtonState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So to achieve a flat appearance, which is the default for DataGridView CheckBoxCells you can write `ButtonState.Checked | ButtonState.Flat` etc..:

```
ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, 11, 11, 22, 22, ButtonState.Checked);
ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, 11, 44, 33, 33, ButtonState.Checked | ButtonState.Flat);
ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, 11, 88, 44, 44, ButtonState.Checked | ButtonState.Flat | ButtonState.Inactive);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help,it woks!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Answer (score 2):

To add onto [@TaW's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw) answer, this solution paints any checkbox column on `dataGridView1`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
        {
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + 1, 
                e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 2,
                (bool) e.FormattedValue ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In VB.NET this is:

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.CellPainting
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim dgv As DataGridView = sender
        If TypeOf dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Then
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, True)
            ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds.X + 1,
                e.CellBounds.Y + 1, e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 2,
                If(CBool(e.FormattedValue), ButtonState.Checked, ButtonState.Normal))
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks.