# Increase the size of Checkbox in #DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, datagridview

i am developing a C# project in Visual Studio. and i have to work with **checkbox** in the **DataGridView**. [Like this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzuuh.png), 
But this Checkbox is very small.
i search a lot on internet but not get an satisfied answer.
is there any solution or frameworks?

Comment: you check out this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171250/how-to-change-checkbox-size-in-datagridviewcheckboxcell`

Comment: but i think it is big enough

Comment: is there anymore suggestion

Comment: As a checkbox is neither a part of C# nor of VS it should have been worth mentioning, which UI framework you are using (WinForms, WPF)...

Comment: i am using Winforms..  thankyou verymuch..
I got the Answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Solution is..**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + 1, 
                e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 2,
                (bool) e.FormattedValue ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```