# Change checkBox Size of Datagridview Checkbox Cell and increase the clickable area

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a checkbox column in my .net core Winform data GridVew.
I already made the checkbox bigger to be easier for the user to click.

My code inside `CellPainting`,

```
                e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
                ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + 5,
                    e.CellBounds.Width - 10, e.CellBounds.Height - 10,
                    (bool)e.FormattedValue ? ButtonState.Checked : ButtonState.Normal);
                e.Handled = true;
```

Those are my reference links,
[How to change checkBox Size in DatagridviewCheckboxCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171250/how-to-change-checkbox-size-in-datagridviewcheckboxcell)
[Increase the size of Checkbox in #DataGridView in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041618/increase-the-size-of-checkbox-in-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

The result is like below,

[image]

But the problem is the click area, even though the size of the checkbox is bigger, I realize the clickable area is still in its original size.
As I show below, the green area is clickable area,
[image]

I want to make the clickable area as big as the checkbox's size as show below,
[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: I would think that you would have to handle the `CellMouseClick` event and use similar logic to create a `Rectangle` and see whether the click was within it.

Comment: @John, can you show me with some code?

Comment: How about you give it go for yourself and then update the question if you strike an actual issue? If you understand the logic of drawing the box within a specific area then understanding the logic of detecting the mouse in that same area should not be a stretch.

Comment: You could also look at the original source code of the standard checkbox cell class and see how it detects clicks on the box and adapt that logic for your specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mouse-click a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` to toggle the *Checked* state, you have to click on the **content** within the cell, clicking on elsewhere within the cell does not change a thing. The content of a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` is that small box area. So, just drawing a bigger box does not resize or reposition (according to the column's `DefaultCellStyle.Alignment`) that *content* area and it remains the same. You need to code for that to tell, the  content area has been clicked and the relevant base methods and events should be invoked.

I'd create custom `DataGridViewCheckBox` column and cell to apply this requirement.

Within your project's namespace, derive a new class from `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`:

```cs
public class CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn : DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
{
    public CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn() : base() =>
        CellTemplate = new CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxCell();

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get => base.CellTemplate;
        set
        {
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxCell)))
                throw new InvalidCastException("CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxCell.");

            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Size), "17, 17")]
    [Description("The size of the check box.")]
    public Size CheckBoxSize { get; set; } = new Size(17, 17);

    // We should copy the new properties.
    public override object Clone()
    {
        var c = base.Clone() as CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn;
        c.CheckBoxSize = CheckBoxSize;
        return c;
    }
}
```

And another one derived from `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`:

```
public class CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxCell : DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
{
    private Rectangle curCellBounds;
    private Rectangle checkBoxRect;

    public CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxCell() : base() { }

    protected override void Paint(
        Graphics g,
        Rectangle clipBounds,
        Rectangle cellBounds,
        int rowIndex,
        DataGridViewElementStates elementState,
        object value,
        object formattedValue,
        string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        // Paint default except the check box parts.
        var parts = paintParts & ~(DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground 
            | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground);

        base.Paint(g, 
            clipBounds, 
            cellBounds, 
            rowIndex, 
            elementState, 
            value, 
            formattedValue, 
            errorText, 
            cellStyle, 
            advancedBorderStyle, 
            parts);
            
        if (curCellBounds != cellBounds)
        {
            // To get the box size...
            var col = OwningColumn as CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn;

            curCellBounds = cellBounds;
            // ToDo: Use col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment or
            // DataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment
            // to position the box. MiddleCenter here...
            checkBoxRect = new Rectangle(
                (cellBounds.Width - col.CheckBoxSize.Width) / 2 + cellBounds.X,
                (cellBounds.Height - col.CheckBoxSize.Height) / 2 + cellBounds.Y,
                col.CheckBoxSize.Width,
                col.CheckBoxSize.Height);
        }

        ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(g, checkBoxRect, (bool)formattedValue 
            ? ButtonState.Checked | ButtonState.Flat 
            : ButtonState.Flat);
    }

    // In case you don't use the `Alignment` property to position the 
    // box. This is to disallow toggling the state if you click on the
    // original content area outside the drawn box.
    protected override void OnContentClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ReadOnly &&
            checkBoxRect.Contains(DataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
            base.OnContentClick(e);
    }

    protected override void OnContentDoubleClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ReadOnly &&
            checkBoxRect.Contains(DataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
            base.OnContentDoubleClick(e);
    }

    // Toggle the checked state by mouse clicks...
    protected override void OnMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);

        if (!ReadOnly && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left &&
            checkBoxRect.Contains(DataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        {
            Value = Value == null || !Convert.ToBoolean(Value);
            DataGridView.RefreshEdit();
            DataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        }    
    }

    // ... and Space key...
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e, int rowIndex)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e, rowIndex);
        if (!ReadOnly && e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            Value = Value == null || !Convert.ToBoolean(Value.ToString());
            DataGridView.RefreshEdit();
            DataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Rebuild and check out the new column type in the grid's designer.

[image: SO73550925A]

In case you have a data-bound grid, set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false` and add the columns manually. For example:

```cs
private readonly static Random rnd = new Random();
//..

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new[]
{
    new DataColumn("Default", typeof(bool)),
    new DataColumn("Custom", typeof(bool))
});

for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    dt.Rows.Add(rnd.Next(0, 2), rnd.Next(0, 2));

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new[]
{
    new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Default" },
    new CustomDataGridViewCheckBoxColumn 
    { 
        HeaderText = "Custom",
        CheckBoxSize = new Size(32, 32) 
    }
});
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

[image: SO73550925B]

Comment: This answer deserves more up votes.

Comment: @StevenSann Thank you Mr. Steven. Appreciate your kind words.