# WinForms, event unable to subscribe from a custom class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, event-handling

I have a custom class `CheckboxHeaderCell` inherit from `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` to add checkbox into any datagridview. The checkbox added successfully, but on checkbox checked event only custom class event trigger but the event in the form (method `HeaderCell_CheckedChanged`) where I added this checkbox never triggers.

[image]

Class: CheckboxHeaderCell

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test.CustomControls
{
    public class CheckboxHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
    {
        public event EventHandler CheckedChanged;

        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public bool IsChecked = false;

        public CheckboxHeaderCell()
        {
            checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            checkBox.Margin = new Padding(0);
            checkBox.Padding = new Padding(0);
            checkBox.Size = new Size(14, 14);
            checkBox.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            checkBox.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
            CheckedChanged = new EventHandler(doNothing);
        }

        public void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsChecked = checkBox.Checked;
            CheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            if (DataGridView != null)
            {
                DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
            }
        }

        public void doNothing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //other methods, paint etc
    }
}
```

I used this class to add custom checkbox into my dgv using below method:

```
private void AddCheckBoxDGV(DataGridView dgv, string columnName)
    {
        if (dgv.Columns.Contains(columnName))
        {
            CustomControls.CheckboxHeaderCell checkboxHeaderCell = new CustomControls.CheckboxHeaderCell();
            checkboxHeaderCell.CheckedChanged += HeaderCell_CheckedChanged;

            dgv.Columns[columnName].HeaderCell = checkboxHeaderCell;
        }
    }
private void HeaderCell_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //do smthing
    }
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a custom delegate named `EventHandler` when .NET already has a delegate with that name that is used for the majority of existing events?

Comment: Why are you using a lambda to invoke a method with the same signature when you could just use the named method in the first place? I think `checkboxHeaderCell.CheckedChanged += HeaderCell_CheckedChanged;` should work or you might need `checkboxHeaderCell.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(HeaderCell_CheckedChanged);`

Comment: @jmcilhinney the delegate is not related to this, I was testing something else.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, if you can see I already used named method, just commented that and added lambda expression to verify. And both not worked.

Comment: If the delegate is not related to the issue then don't include it. Post ALL code that is relevant and ONLY code that is relevant. If you include code that isn't relevant then it's a distraction from the actual issue. With that in mind, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: As for using the named method, I didn't that you'd commented that out so I should have looked more closely, but that's also something to mention. I didn't expect that that would be linked to the issue but the extra code doesn't really make sense, but if you're just doing that for testing then that's obviously fine, but something to mention.

Comment: okay I will update.

Comment: No, you create a **custom** `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` to replace the default `HeaderCell` of a **custom** `DataGridViewColumn` whose `CellTemplate` is a **custom** `DataGridViewCell`. You need to have them all. So, what are you trying to do here? a _Check All_ header or something else?

Comment: yes you got it right, its a custom headercell, as a check all header.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `HeaderCell` does nothing but creates a `CheckBox` that you will never see or access as UI element. Neither on the `HeaderCell` nor anywhere else on the grid. So, I don't understand how:

> *The checkbox added successfully ...*

You must add a *Control* to some `Parent.Controls` collection and that `Parent` must be added directly (itself) or indirectly (its parent) to a top-level control. A `Form` for example. The `HeaderCell` is not a Control to be used as such.

To proof the concept, add the `CheckBox` to `yourGrid.Controls`, you'll see it at the very top left, tick it and you'll get the `CheckedChanged` event raised.

---

I understand that you need a custom `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` with a master CheckBox on the `HeaderCell` to check/uncheck all. Here's an example.

▶ **HeaderCell**

In the first section, derive a new class from `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` and,

- Add a property to get/set the [`CheckState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkstate?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.CheckState)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) of the master CheckBox. `Checked` if all the cells are checked, `Unchecked` if non, and `Indeterminate` if not all are checked.
- Override the `OnMouseClick` method to toggle the state and set the property which,
- The setter calls a method to set the `Value` property of the owning column's cells to `true` or `false`.
- Add an event to raise when the current `CheckState` changes to different value.

```cs
public class CheckAllColumnHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
{
    enum MouseState : int
    {
        Normal,
        Hot,
        Down
    }
        
    CheckState _checkState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    MouseState _mouseState = MouseState.Normal; // See the mouse methods...
    Rectangle _checkBoxRect; // See the Paint method...
    bool _suppressUpdate = false; // To avoid redundant calls...

    public CheckState CheckState
    {
        get => _checkState;
        set
        {
            if (_checkState != value)
            {
                if (DataGridView.RowCount == 0 ||
                    DataGridView.Rows[0].IsNewRow) return;

                _checkState = value;
                DataGridView?.InvalidateCell(this);
                SetCellsCheckState();
                OnCheckedChanged(new HeaderCellCheckedChangedEventArgs(value));
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetCellsCheckState()
    {
        if (CheckState != CheckState.Indeterminate)
        {
            bool state = CheckState == CheckState.Checked;
            foreach (var row in DataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow) row.Cells[ColumnIndex].Value = state;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && 
            DataGridView.RowCount > 0 && !DataGridView.Rows[0].IsNewRow &&
            _checkBoxRect.Contains(DataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        {
            _suppressUpdate = true;
            CheckState = CheckState == CheckState.Checked || 
                CheckState == CheckState.Indeterminate
                ? CheckState.Unchecked
                : CheckState.Checked;
            _suppressUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<HeaderCellCheckedChangedEventArgs> CheckedChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCheckedChanged(HeaderCellCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
```

The second section is to update the state of the master CheckBox when some relevant events of the `DataGridView` occur. For example, when the user tick/untick a cell of the owning column, when adding or removing rows ...

```cs
    protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()
    {
        base.OnDataGridViewChanged();

        if (DataGridView != null)
        {
            DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged -= OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
            DataGridView.CellValueChanged -= OnDataGridViewOnCellValueChanged;
            DataGridView.RowsAdded -= OnDataGridViewRowsAdded;
            DataGridView.RowsRemoved -= OnDataGridViewRowsRemoved;

            DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
            DataGridView.CellValueChanged += OnDataGridViewOnCellValueChanged;
            DataGridView.RowsAdded += OnDataGridViewRowsAdded;
            DataGridView.RowsRemoved += OnDataGridViewRowsRemoved;
        }
    }

    private void OnDataGridViewOnCellValueChanged(object sender,
        DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex == ColumnIndex)
        {
            if (DataGridView.NewRowIndex == e.RowIndex)
                DataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
            else
                UpdateCheckState();
        }
    }

    private void OnDataGridViewRowsAdded(object sender,
        DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e) => UpdateCheckState();

    private void OnDataGridViewRowsRemoved(object sender,
        DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e) => UpdateCheckState();

    private void OnCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataGridView.CurrentCell?.ColumnIndex == ColumnIndex)
            UpdateCheckState();
    }

    private void UpdateCheckState()
    {            
        if (DataGridView is null) return;
        DataGridView.EndEdit();
        DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        if (_suppressUpdate) return;
        int total = DataGridView.RowCount;
        if (DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows) total--;
        int chkCount = DataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Aggregate(0, (count, row) =>
            {
                count += (bool)row.Cells[ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue ? 1 : 0;
                return count;
            });

        var current = chkCount == 0
            ? CheckState.Unchecked
            : chkCount == total
            ? CheckState.Checked
            : CheckState.Indeterminate;

        if (current != _checkState)
        {
            _checkState = current;                
            OnCheckedChanged(new HeaderCellCheckedChangedEventArgs(_checkState));
        }
    }
```

The last section here, drawing the master CheckBox. Override the mouse events to update the *mouse state* which is used in the `Paint` method to determine which [`CheckBoxState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.checkboxstate?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) to draw. I'll use the [`CheckBoxRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkboxrenderer?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.CheckBoxRenderer)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) to draw the `CheckBox` in this example. You can try the [`ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawcheckbox?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev17IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) instead or draw it the way you want.

```cs
    protected override void OnMouseMove(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        if (Control.MouseButtons != MouseButtons.None) return;

        if (_checkBoxRect.Contains(DataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        {
            if (_mouseState != MouseState.Hot)
            {
                _mouseState = MouseState.Hot;
                DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
            }
        }
        else if (_mouseState != MouseState.Normal)
        {
            _mouseState = MouseState.Normal;
            DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left &&
            _checkBoxRect.Contains(DataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        {
            _mouseState = MouseState.Down;
            DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _checkBoxRect
            .Contains(DataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))
        {
            _mouseState = MouseState.Normal;
            DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(int rowIndex)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(rowIndex);

        if (_mouseState != MouseState.Normal)
        {
            _mouseState = MouseState.Normal;
            DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics,
        Rectangle clipBounds,
        Rectangle cellBounds,
        int rowIndex,
        DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState,
        object value,
        object formattedValue,
        string errorText,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
        DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
        DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        // You don't want to draw the HeaderText. Do you?
        // If yes, comment this and don't center the 
        // check box horizontally.
        paintParts &= ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground;

        base.Paint(graphics,
            clipBounds,
            cellBounds,
            rowIndex,
            dataGridViewElementState,
            value,
            formattedValue,
            errorText,
            cellStyle,
            advancedBorderStyle,
            paintParts);

        bool enabled = DataGridView.Enabled;
        CheckBoxState state = CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;

        switch (CheckState)
        {
            case CheckState.Checked:
                state = !enabled ? CheckBoxState.CheckedDisabled
                    : _mouseState == MouseState.Down
                    ? CheckBoxState.CheckedPressed
                    : _mouseState == MouseState.Hot
                    ? CheckBoxState.CheckedHot
                    : CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal;
                break;
            case CheckState.Indeterminate:
                state = !enabled ? CheckBoxState.MixedDisabled
                    : _mouseState == MouseState.Down
                    ? CheckBoxState.MixedPressed
                    : _mouseState == MouseState.Hot
                    ? CheckBoxState.MixedHot
                    : CheckBoxState.MixedNormal;
                break;
            case CheckState.Unchecked:
                state = !enabled ? CheckBoxState.UncheckedDisabled
                    : _mouseState == MouseState.Down
                    ? CheckBoxState.UncheckedPressed
                    : _mouseState == MouseState.Hot
                    ? CheckBoxState.UncheckedHot
                    : CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
                break;
        }

        Size sz = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(graphics, state);
        Point pt = new Point(
                cellBounds.X + (cellBounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2,
                cellBounds.Y + (cellBounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2);
        _checkBoxRect = new Rectangle(pt, sz);

        CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(graphics, pt, state);
    }
}
```

For the `HeaderCell` custom event, the following custom event arguments class is used to pass the new state.

```cs
public class HeaderCellCheckedChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public HeaderCellCheckedChangedEventArgs(CheckState state)
    {
        CheckState = state;
    }

    public CheckState CheckState { get; }
}
```

For some thoughts, See:

- [Change checkBox Size of Datagridview Checkbox Cell and increase the clickable area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73556729/14171304)
- [Custom DataGridViewCell repainting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74089369/14171304)

▶ **Column & Cell**

Derive a new class from `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`. Unless you want to override the `Paint` method to draw the CheckBox yourself. You don't need to do anything here. It's mainly used to set the `CellTemplate` of the column class.

```cs
public class CheckAlCheckBoxlCell : DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
{
    public CheckAlCheckBoxlCell() { }
}
```

... and derive another from `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`.

```cs
public class CheckAllCheckBoxColumn : DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
{
    private readonly CheckAllColumnHeaderCell _headerCell;

    public CheckAllCheckBoxColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new CheckAlCheckBoxlCell();
        _headerCell = new CheckAllColumnHeaderCell();
        HeaderCell = _headerCell;
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get => base.CellTemplate;
        set
        {
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CheckAlCheckBoxlCell)))
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CheckAlCheckBoxlCell.");

            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public CheckState CheckState
    {
        get => _headerCell.CheckState;
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case CheckState.Checked:
                case CheckState.Indeterminate:
                    _headerCell.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                    break;
                default:
                    _headerCell.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

▶ **Implementation**

Compile and add the custom column by the designer. You'll find in the grid's columns designer a new item is listed and named `CheckAllCheckBoxColumn`. You need to subscribe to the `CheckedChanged` event by code though. Assuming the column name is `checkAllColumn`:

```cs
// In your Form...
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    (checkAllColumn.HeaderCell as CheckAllColumnHeaderCell)
        .CheckedChanged += OnColumnCheckAllChanged;
            
}

private void OnColumnCheckAllChanged(object sender, HeaderCellCheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.CheckState);
}
```

Or, do it all by code:

```cs
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    var checkAllColumn = new CheckAllCheckBoxColumn();
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkAllColumn);
    (checkAllColumn.HeaderCell as CheckAllColumnHeaderCell)
        .CheckedChanged += OnColumnCheckAllChanged;
            
}
```

[image: SO78242105]